# How can I assign a name to the SUM column?

Tags: sql-server

how can I assign a column name to the SUM column ?

i.e.

```
select OwnerUserId, SUM(PostScore)
INTO Experts
from ...
```

I get this error:

> An object or column name is missing or
>   empty. For SELECT INTO statements,
>   verify each column has a name. For
>   other statements, look for empty alias
>   names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are
>   not allowed. Change the alias to a
>   valid name.

I guess because the column containing the results of SUM has not name.

Comment: SQL Server 2003 ?? I'm aware of 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 (i.e. 2010) - which one is it now??

Comment: @marc_s they probably have Windows Server 2003 as operating system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all there's no SQL-Server 2003. Only 2000, 2005, 2008 (and then 2008R2, 2012 and the latest 2014).

As for the name - called alias - you can use `AS`. This is the standard SQL syntax:

```
SELECT OwnerUserId, SUM(PostScore) AS PostScoreSum
INTO Experts 
FROM ...
```

But `AS` is optional, so you can also alias a column without it:

```
SELECT OwnerUserId, SUM(PostScore)  PostScoreSum
INTO Experts 
FROM ...
```

You can also use the (proprietary, only in SQL-Server) `alias = column` syntax:

```
SELECT OwnerUserId, PostScoreSum = SUM(PostScore)  
INTO Experts 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alias any column, computed or not by using the `AS` keyword:

```
SELECT OwnerUserId AS MyUserId, SUM(PostScore) As Score
INTO Experts
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select OwnerUserId, SUM(PostScore) as mySum
INTO Experts
from ...
```

or

```
select OwnerUserId, SUM(PostScore) [mySum]
INTO Experts
from ...
```