# Dynamically setting column name in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a **Query** like this:

```
Select COUNT(*) from tblAnswerType where AnswerType = 'RadioButton'
```

It shows a result of 33, but in the answer no column name is specified. I want to specify a column name, e.g: RadioButton/RDB.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign a name to the SUM column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789269/how-can-i-assign-a-name-to-the-sum-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name any between []

```
Select COUNT(*) AS [RadioButton/RDB] 
from tblAnswerType 
where AnswerType = 'RadioButton'
```