# Adding a heading to my query results

Tags: sql

```
Select SUM(feespaid)
FROM tblrecplayers
```

The result i get is

```
sum numeric

1150
```

I'm trying to have the output

```
Total Paid

1150
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks, this solved it :)

Comment: @jpw you should make this an answer

Comment: @jpw how humbling of you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign a name to the SUM column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789269/how-can-i-assign-a-name-to-the-sum-column)

Answer (score 1):

`Select SUM(feespaid) AS "Total Paid" FROM tblrecplayers`

The point to make here is using `as` which changes the result column name to its entered value over the original column name. So for this instance, you are asking for the `sum of feespaid` with a column name of `Total Paid` being returned.