# fetching the sum in sqlite returning undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm having trouble fetching the sum in sqlite, its returning a undefined in my javascript code. can you please help me? here are my codes.

here is my index.js code

``````
    function displayExpenses(results) {
        var length = results.rows.length;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var item = results.rows.item(i);
            var parsedMon = parseInt(item.mon_value);
            var moneyVal = (parsedMon).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
            console.log(moneyVal);
        }
    }
`````
here is my sqlite code
```
fetchExpenses: function(displayExpenses) {
        databaseHandler.db.readTransaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT SUM (mon_value) FROM money WHERE mon_type = '-'",
                    [],
                    function(tx, results) {
                        displayExpenses(results);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1b19.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgI6F.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/82UN5.png
``````

Answer (score 0):

item.mon_value may not work unless you give it an alias like this:

```
SELECT SUM (mon_value) as mon_value_sum FROM ...
...

var parsedMon = parseInt(item.mon_value_sum)
```

You also might want to look at this: [How can I assign a name to the SUM column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789269/how-can-i-assign-a-name-to-the-sum-column)

Comment: OMG! thank you for helping me figuring this out! thank you so much! it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please select my answer if it helped. Thanks